# mysql server 5.5 syntax error

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I am currently learning how to put together a database driven website.

I am learning PHP from [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-mysql/)

They are plainly using a lower version of PHP, this command is returning an error.

```
CREATE TABLE joke ( ->   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ->   joketext TEXT, ->   jokedate DATE NOT NULL -> ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Here is the error,

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '->   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ->   joketext TEXT, ->   jokeda' at line 1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I am hunting about online and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the problem seems to be the fact the the `->` is just a kind of *prompt*

The `->` shouldn't be part of the command you enter.

The command should be:

```
CREATE TABLE joke (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, joketext TEXT, jokedate DATE NOT NULL) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Beautiful,Thanks a lot. Why didn't I spot that?

Comment: @hvaan - happy to help! If I've answered your question please [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) it